# TFS & Visual Studio integration - Get Latest does not always work?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

I'm developing in Visual Studio 2005, using TFS as the source control. Whenever I haven't been working on the solution for a while, I always do a recursive Get Latest in Solution Explorer.

However, this doesn't always seem to work. If I know I don't have the latest version of a file, even right-clicking this (in Solution Explorer), choosing Get Specific Version and ticking the "Force get" box doesn't work.

I seem to need to open up the TFS Source Control window, and there force a Get of the file in question.

Also, the Solution Explorer often has the little "checked out to someone else" icon next to files, but when I check in Source Control, they're not checked out at all!

I'd just like to know if these problems are widespread, whether they persist in VS2008 (I haven't used TFS for a big project in 2008 yet), and if there are any fixes or workarounds.

Comment: Can't comment on "widespread" but can confirm that I have had the exact same experiences. I have code marked checked out by someone else for weeks yet I am the only person working on it.

Comment: We are using Visual Studio 2008 with TFS 2012 for SSIS projects and we are experiencing the same issue. Sometimes files that nobody has checked out are simply not updated in your local workspace when you do Get Latest Version from the Solution Explorer.
It seems to always work when using the TFS Source Control window's Get Latest Version, but how do you teach n project members to stop using the Solution Explorer they have been using for five years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) I would not make a habit out of Get Latest from Solution Explorer.  Even if it always worked 100% bug free, it is far slower and less reliable than doing it from the command line or Source Control Explorer.  SlnExp has to crawl your whole project structure and issue non-recursive calls...pseudo algorithm:

```
parse sln file
foreach project in sln
    TFS_GET makefile
    parse makefile
    enumerate sourcefiles[]
    TFS_GET sourcefiles[]
loop
```

SCE requires no parsing and issues one single recursive webservice call.  In addition to the performance gain, this is much safer:

(a) Build-time dependencies aren't always part of a project's file list.  Executable tools, 3rd party assemblies, and deployment scripts are all common examples.  SCE will download them, SlnExp won't.

(b) Scoping Get calls down to specific files won't yield the expected result when a file is renamed or moved.  At best, the "old" name is deleted from disk; at worst, nothing appears to happen at all.  (this may be the cause of the bug you reported)  In order for a file to truly be renamed/moved in sync with the server, the old & new paths must both be inside the scope of the Get.

2) There have been many bug fixes to the SlnExp "glyphs" over the years.  I won't claim that VS2008 SP1 is perfect in this regard but it is definitely improved.

Comment: But how can you deactivate the Get Latest Version in Solution Explorer to make sure nobody in your team uses it? OTherwise it (the change to TFS Source Control Explorer) will never happen..... not in a big project with a history of using SLN Explorer for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `Get specific version` **even checking both checkboxes** won't get you the latest file. Most commonly what happens is that you've made a change to a file, and you want to undo those changes by re-getting the latest version. Well... that's what `Undo pending changes` is for and not the purpose of `Get specific version`.

If in doubt:

- undo pending check in on the file(s) before you do 'get latest'
- do a compare afterwards to make sure your file matches the expected version
- run a recursive 'compare' on your whole project afterwards to see what's different
- keep an eye on pending changes window and sometimes you may need to check 'take server version' to resolve an incompatible pending change

And this one's my favorite that I just discovered :

- check the `Output` window for messages such as this :

  Warning - Unable to refresh R:\TFS-PROJECTS\www.example.com\ExampleMVC\Example MVC\Example MVC.csproj because you have a pending edit.

Yes this **critical** message appears in the output window. No other notifications!
Nothing in pending changes and no other dialog message telling you that the file you just requested explicitly was not retrieved! And yes - you resolve this by just running `Undo pending changes` and getting the file.

Comment: But that is intended behaviour in Visual Studio and is not a bug. Get Latest Version is NOT supposed to overwrite your local changes.
The problem described here is that Get Latest Version sometimes just doesn't fetch the latest version of a file that you HAVEN'T edited or otherwise checked out. That is a real bug and a very severe one.